# If clause sentence which one is correct from these two sentences?

Tags: clauses

First question

I want to show that in the future or present it's not possible for him to bend the knee

> 1. Even if you want to bend the knee you will not be able to do that
> 2. Even if you wanted to bend the knee you wouldn't be able to do that

Which one is correct and why?

Second question

> 1. Back then, if I wanted to have it, I would get it
> 2. Back then, if I had wanted to have itm I would have gotten it

Which one is correct and why?

Third question

Can we use the second structure of if clause to speak about some thing hard to be true but in the future?

Comment: Why do you think any of your sentences are *incorrect*?  You will need to add more detail so we can write a good answer to your question.   The short answer is that all are fine, but the meaning of each is slightly different.  Also, I don't understand what you mean by "the second structure of if clause".  Do you mean the [*second conditional*](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/second-conditional.html)?

Comment: Also, you should be aware that the expression "to bend the knee" is, as far as I know, unique to the fictional HBO series *Game of Thrones*.  Most every historical reference would simply say "to kneel".

Comment: @Andrew  "To bend the knee" is an utterly standard if somewhat poetic expression for "to submit to" or "to demonstrate submission to", although it cam also mean to physically move one's knee, perhaps in a medical context. See https://www.etymologynerd.com/blog/bend-the-knee and *O God, We Humbly Bend the Knee* by Stephen Massett (1888); *Happyland, Or, The King of Elysia* by Reginald De Koven (1905); *The Coptic morning service for the Lord's day* (1882; p 62); *Catholic Champion* "We should bend the knee before the Blessed Sacrament". Google Books search finds lots of medical & sports uses.

Comment: @andrew see [this Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bend+the+knee%2Ckneel+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#) which references *The Christian Hymn Book* by Alexander Campbell 1866; *Lake Superior and Other Poems* by W J Massingham · 1904; *Excelsior Recitations* 1910; *The Lutheran Companion - Vol 28  p 71; (1920); The Latter-day Saints' Millennial Star - Voe 44 - p 96 (1882); Hutchings' Illustrated California Magazine - Vol 1 p 42 " And now stand up a freeman , or forever bend the knee"; The Free Thought Magazine - Vol 18 p 218 1900 & many more

Answer (score 1):

"If you want to bend the knee, you will not be allowed to" is oriented to the future. It does not preclude your being allowed to bend the knee right now.

"If you wanted to bend the knee, you would not be allowed to" is oriented to the present. You are not going to be permitted now, but you may be permitted to do so in the future.

"If you had wanted to bend the knee, you would not have been allowed to" relates to the past, but is silent as to present and future.